# Правильное проектирование проекта на Java

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Доброго времени суток !

Хочу научиться правильно проектировать свои приложения. Чтобы код был читаемым для других программистов. Знаю, что существуют *паттерны проектирования*, но я не умею ими пользоваться.

Хочу, чтобы вы помогли понять, как мне лучше спроектировать данную задачу:

- Есть класс, который конвертирует XML файл и возвращает `List<>` с этими данными.
- Есть класс, который делает манипуляции с изображением (в параметре метода путь к файлу берется из XML), и этот метод должен возвратить n-ное количество картинок (их очень много), так как одну большую обрезаю несколько раз. Можно ли сделать какой-нибудь метод в этом классе, чтобы фабрично создавать картинки?
- И класс, который записывает эти картинки в базу данных.

Есть идея реализовать потоки (`Threads`) в момент деления картинки на части и записи их в БД.

Какие паттерны подходят больше под мою задачу? И объясните новичку, каким образом Вы, профессионалы, их выбираете?
Код уже написан, но его я бы назвал плохим кодом. Хочу научиться делать все правильно! Спасибо за понимание.

Comment: Годный и риторически хороший вопрос. +1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Тема применимости паттернов проектирования тянет на весьма объёмную статью или даже книгу, уложить всё это в ответ на форуме невозможно. Но, раз уж вы спросили, вот несколько советов:

1. Если плохо даётся понимание паттернов проектирования - читайте [Паттерны проектирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20216992/) Фрименов, Сьерры и Бейтса. В этой книге очень доходчиво объясняются самые распространённые паттерны.
2. Почитайте классический труд на эту тему - [Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/) "Банды Четырёх". Эту книгу удобнее всего использовать как справочник, в котором описаны назначение, области применения, детали реализации и выгоды от использования конкретных паттернов.
3. Помимо классических паттернов, описанных в этих книгах, существуют паттерны, применяющиеся в конкретных областях: enterprise, параллельное программирование, веб-разработка и т. д. Существуют каталоги паттернов, в которых вы можете с ними ознакомиться.
4. Подумайте, точно ли вам нужны именно паттерны. Существует множество приёмов [рефакторинга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3), позволяющих сделать код более чистым, красивым, читаемым, надёжным. Вы называете свой код плохим - задумайтесь, почемы вы так считаете. Много повторяющихся участков - выносите в отдельные методы. Много `switch/case` или многступенчатые `if/else` - выносите в отдельные классы. Метод в пару сотен строк - разбивайте на более короткие, делающие осмысленные и законченные куски работы. Об этом можно подробно почитать в книге [Рефакторинг. Улучшение существующего кода](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1308678/) Фаулера и компании, либо кратко - в [этой шпаргалке](https://refactoring.guru/ru?-s).
5. Ещё раз подумайте, нужны ли вам паттерны. Основная задача паттернов проектирования - делать код легко расширяемым и изменяемым. Подумайте, будет ли ваше приложение изменяться, если будет, то как и в каких местах. Если таких мест мало или нет, возможно, вы занимаетесь overengineering'ом, то есть бессмысленным усложнением кода.
6. Никогда не думайте "куда бы мне пристроить паттерн в моей программе". Такой подход - прямой путь к бессмысленному усложнению кода. Правильный ход мыслей - "в моей программе есть задача, которая хорошо решается при помощи паттерна". Для верности сверяйте формулировку вашей задачи с областями применимости паттерна в каталогах паттернов.

Грамотное проектирование приложений - вопрос опыта. Чтобы получить этот опыт - максимально критически рассматривайте свой код, ищите проблемы в дизайне, исправляйте их. Со временем вы начнёте чётко видеть "шероховатости" и потенциальные ошибки, а позже - предугатывать их на этапе проектирования.

Посоветовать что-либо более конкретное в рамках ответа сложно. Если у вас есть конкретные вопросы по проектированию приложений, не стесняйтесь их задавать. Вам наверняка помогут, если вы более подробно опишете свою задачу и приведёте свой вариант решения.

Comment: Лучше ответа и не придумать ! Что касается книги Фрименов, Сьерры и Бейтса, то я уже на второй главе. И скорее всего Вы правы, стоит задуматься о рефакторинге... столько всего, а я один =) 

А что касается моей задачи, мы сможем это обсудить в чате ? Если конечно же у Вас будет минутка. Есть пару идей, хочу уточнить в каком направлении иду.

Comment: Качественный, методологический ответ, не содержащий, правда, *практических рекомендаций по решению конкретной задачи*. Но мой +1 за последние два абзаца.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, к сожалению, задача в вопросе описано недостаточно конкретно, чтобы можно было дать практические рекомендации. kxxko, вам стоит задать новый вопрос, в котором вы более подробно опишете вашу задачу. В частности, как именно загружаются и обрабатываются изображения, какова структура XML-файла, может ли быть одновременно запущено несколько копий приложения и т. д. Мы, конечно, можем обсудить это в чате, но, если вы зададите вопрос, его увидит больше людей, и, соответственно, вы сможете получить советы, базирующиеся не только на моём мнении.

Comment: @fori1ton мне кажется стоит попробовать поговорить с Вами, что то подсказывает, чужого мнения и не надо будет. Код приложения есть, не знаю как спроектировать. Я прохожу практику, и делаю приложение для фирмы. Хочу  красиво написать код и спроектировать. Я бы Вам показал бы скриншоты моего видения, а Вы бы подсказали - в том ли направлении иду

Comment: Я придерживаюсь мнения, что одна голова - хорошо, а несколько тысяч голов - лучше. Но, если вы настаиваете, можете создать обсуждение в чате и выложить туда свои наработки, я постараюсь вам помочь.

Comment: `Код приложения есть, не знаю как спроектировать` -- уже интересно. Обычно правильный путь начинается с другого конца: *оформление* требований -> проектирование -> написание кода.

Comment: @fori1ton http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26853/

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд целью должен быть не столько читаемый код (хотя это не мало важно и идет рука об руку с последующим утверждением), а более *дешевый* код. Под *дешевым* - я подразумеваю такой код, который дешевле изменять.

Любое приложение меняется со временем, добавляются новые требования, существующие требования меняются и т.п. Программистам приходится менять программу, чтобы она соотвтествовала этим изменениям. Чем быстрее и удобнее эти изменения можно будет внести, чем меньше проблем и ошибок это вызовет - тем *дешевле* они будут. А чем *дешевле* - тем конкурентоспособнее. Все эти паттерны и подходы и т.п., ИМХО, как раз направлены на то, чтобы помочь сделать код более *дешевым*.

Поэтому, в процессе разработки, старайтесь оценивать то, что получается на предмет того, как Вам это потом, возможно, придется менять. А паттерны - они просто покажут Вам примеры того, как другие разработчики решают различные проблемы (и с ними стоит познакомится), но они не дадут Вам панацею от всех бед.